# JOptionPane Can Not DIsplay Everything

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Hello SO Community I have recently changed my program from a Scanner input and display to a JOptionPane input and display, It is set up to display the investment over a course of user specified years

Currently if the number of years is more than 3 it will terminate the program, how would I go about solving this and/or creating a single pop up window to show the results? Thank you in advance everyone.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Investing {

public static void main (String[] args){

    double amount;

    double principal;

    double rate;

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    String principals = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter The Principal");
    principal = Double.parseDouble(principals);

    String rates = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter The Rate Of Interest");
    rate = Double.parseDouble(rates);

    String years = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter The Number Of Investment Years");
    double g = Double.parseDouble(years);
    String zs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please Enter Annual Contribution");
    double z = Double.parseDouble(zs);

    amount = principal;
    for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
        amount *= 1 + rate/100;
        amount+= z;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, year + "  " + amount, zs, year);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using JOptionPane wrongly

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, year + "  " + amount, zs, year);
```

You are passing year as message type, so it fails after year 3. you should do

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, year + "  " + amount, "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
```

Comment: This is good it fixes the problem,however how would i put all of this information into a "table" on the JOptionPane in one display?

Comment: `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` has the message parameter as an `Object` so you can also pass any `JComponent` as the message. You can build a `JTable` and pass that to `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` as `Object message`

Answer (score 0):

```
interest = principal * Math.pow((1 + rate/100),year);
amount += z;
```

instead of

> amount *= 1 + rate/100;
>               amount+= z;

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
 null,year + " " + amount,zs,year, "Compound Interest",
 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
```

[Refer this](http://www.ece.uprm.edu/~borges/guis.pdf)

Comment: I appreciate the answer it does make the program a little easier, but the problem is that I keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: JOptionPane: type must be one of JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE or JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
 at javax.swing.JOptionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.java:2083)
 at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1842)
 at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:858)
 at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)

Comment: @Minotaur try this. your optionpane wants to know what is the message is it an error message or an information message etc..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a `StringBuilder` to format your text within the `for` loop and then use that to display it within your dialog.

```
amount = principal;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
    amount *= 1 + rate/100;
    amount+= z;
    sb.append(new String(year + " " + amount + '\n'));
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString(), "Amount Owing", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation to display all the variables in the messageDialogBox and can use messageDialogBox with only two parameters for this purpose

```
for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
    amount *= (1 + rate/100);
    amount+= z;
    String a = year + " " + amount + " "+ zs + " " + year;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, a);
    }
```

You are using showMessageDialog with your variables(year+" ",amount,zs,year) as it's parameters

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.MessageType);
```

which gets error when year is greater than 3 as there are only three types of message.For  more read this 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJOptionPanetoDisplayaMessage.htm